# C -- compile without error but function not working

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to write a function to handle inputs by users for allowing them to enter "y", "yeah", "sure", "absolutely" and so on to answer "yes or no" question. Here is part of my code, compile without errors but is not working.

```
void distinguish_string(char s[])
{
  if (s[0] == 'y')
      s = "yes";
  else if (s[0] == 'n')
      s = "no";
  else 
      printf("Please eneter a valid answer. Like 'yes' or 'no', 'y' or 'n'.\n> ");
}

void play(Node **currentNode)
{
    char answerOfQuestion[60];
    ........
    fgets(answerOfQuestion, 60, stdin);
    strtok(answerOfQuestion, "\n");
    distinguish_string(answerOfQuestion);
    .......
}
```

Since I need to later use

```
if(strcmp(answerOfQuestion,"yes") == 0)
```

So my function must return "yes" instead of int like 1 or 0.

Any way to solve this?
Please help

Comment: It is actually way easier to have that function return 0 or 1 and handle the *printing* in the code that calls it. Also, make it return `-1` for an invalid entry so you can ask again in a simple loop.

Comment: After calling distinguish_string(), won't answerOfQuestion be pointed to the small literal rather then the original char[60]?  If you then did another fgets ...  Maybe the literal would get protected, maybe not.

Comment: No, @mark, it won't. `answerOfQuestion` is local to `play`. A copy of the pointer is passed to `distinguish_string` as `s`, and then `s` may be changed to point elsewhere, but that doesn't affect `answerOfQuestion`.

Comment: `s = "yes";` should be `strcpy(s, "yes");` , etc.

Comment: @Tom, you're right, I forgot C parameters were default passed by value. In that case, N.M's point is correct instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the canonical string into the array (instead of just modifying what the local pointer in the function points at):

```
void distinguish_string(char s[])
{
  if (s[0] == 'y')
      strcpy(s, "yes");
  else if (s[0] == 'n')
      strcpy(s, "no");
  else 
      printf("Please enter a valid answer. Like 'yes' or 'no', 'y' or 'n'.\n> ");
}
```

Note, though, that the calling code has no way of knowing that the answer given was 'sure' or 'absolutely' and doing anything about it because it doesn't return a status or anything.

This is an unusual interface; most often you don't go overwriting an input argument like that.  However, give or take the error detection, it is not wrong.

Comment: Then how can I handle the input like "sure" or "absolutely"? Can I write if (s[0] == 'y') || (s == 'sure') || (s == 'absolutely')  and then strcpy all of them into "yes" ??

Comment: Yes, you can use `strncmp(s, "abs", 3) == 0)` to spot words starting `abs` and `strcmp(s, "sure") == 0` to compare with 'sure', etc. and then copy the canonical word over the input string. That's relatively straight-forward. I think you should have a return type (`int` or `bool`, probably), and the function should return one value (e.g. `false` or 0) to indicate that the answer was unrecognized (please enter a new response) and another (e.g. `true` or 1) to indicate that the answer has been validated. Of course, you might need to be careful about taking "absolutely not!" as "yes". 'Tis tricky!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!